# responsive design documentation confusion

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, responsive-design

In https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout-item/specification it says:

> large-device-size - If the viewport is divided into 12 parts, this
> attribute indicates the relative space the container occupies on
> device-types larger than desktop. It is expressed as an integer from 1
> through 12.
>
> medium-device-size - If the viewport is divided into 12 parts, **this
> attribute indicates the relative space the container occupies on
> device-types larger than tablet**. It is expressed as an integer from 1
> through 12.

Yet, in the Documentation tab it says:

> If you specify the size and small-device-size attributes, the size
> attribute applies to small mobile phones, and the small-device-size
> applies to smart phones. The device sizing attributes are additive and
> apply to devices of the specified size and larger. For example, **if you
> set medium-device-size=10 and don't set large-device-size, then the
> medium-device-size setting applies to tablets**, desktops, and larger
> devices. You'd also have to set size to apply to devices smaller than
> tablets.

I find that contradictory. Can someone clarify if medium-device-size includes or does not include tablet? And similarly if small includes smart phones and if large includes desktops? I don't have devices to test and unfortunately can't test this in playground - but I did try by using Chrome developer tools to mock mobile on my desktop and was surprised to discover that the respective devices are excluded.. ie. small-device-size does not include smart phone. However, can't be sure if the simulated tabled/phone on Chrome worked or not. I imagine it will be same in Aura.

Answer (score 0):

If you **set medium-device-size to 10 and don't set large-device-size**, then the medium-device-size **includes** tablets.

If you **set medium-device-size to 12**, then the medium-device-size **does not include** tablets.